# Svm-scaling for training and testing using libsvm on matlab

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm

I want to use SVM-scale for both training and testing on Matlab using libsvm. In libsvm document implement this but using Python and I need for Matlab. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, you can directly use the rescale function to your matrices and provide them as input to training and testing functions.
Documentation - https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rescale.html